# How to fix segmentation fault in AVL deletion operation when rebalancing?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, avl-tree, tree-balancing

I am implementing an AVL tree and my search and insertion functions work properly, but I get a segmentation fault with my remove function. I have implemented a BST tree correctly before, so I know the issue is with the rebalancing of the tree rather than the initial deletion of a node.

Since my insertion operation works with the rebalancing, I also know the issue is not with the rotation functions themselves.

I have tried different strategies such as maintaining a balance factor at each node and have tried implementing other source code I have found online but I always end up with a segmentation fault and really cannot find where. I'd appreciate any help.

```
class AVL
{
public:
    AVL();

    Node* insert(int num);
    Node* search(int num);
    Node* remove(int num);
    void print();
    void comparisonPrint();

private:
    int comparisonCount;
    Node* root;
    int max(int a, int b);
    int getHeight(Node* t);
    int getBalance(Node* t);
    Node* insert(Node* &t, int num);
    Node* rotateWithLeftChild(Node* t);
    Node* rotateWithRightChild(Node* t);
    Node* doubleRotateWithLeftChild(Node* t);
    Node* doubleRotateWithRightChild(Node* t);

    Node* search(Node* t, int num);
    Node* removeMin(Node* parent, Node* node);
    Node* remove(Node* &t, int num);
    void print(Node* t);
    //print
};

int AVL::max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b)? a : b;
}
int AVL::getHeight(Node* t)
{
    return (t == NULL) ? 0 : t->height;
}
int AVL::getBalance(Node* t)
{
    if(t == NULL)
        return 0;
    return getHeight(t->leftChild) - getHeight(t->rightChild);
}

//helper function for remove - finds min
Node* AVL::removeMin(Node* parent, Node* node) //removes node, but does not delete - returns ptr instead
{
    if(node != NULL)
    {
        if(node->leftChild != NULL) //go to leftmost child in right subtree
            return removeMin(node, node->leftChild);
        else //min val
        {
            parent->leftChild = node->rightChild;
            return node;
        }
    }
    else //subtree empty - incorrect use of function
        return NULL;
}

Node* AVL::remove(Node* &t, int num)
{
    cout << num;
    if(t != NULL)
    {

        if(num > t->key)
        {
            comparisonCount++;
            remove(t->rightChild, num);
        }
        else if(num < t->key)
        {
            comparisonCount++;
            remove(t->leftChild, num);
        }
        else if(t->leftChild != NULL && t->rightChild != NULL)
        {
            comparisonCount++;
            //2 children
            Node* minRightSubtree = removeMin(t, t->rightChild);
            t->key = minRightSubtree->key;
            delete minRightSubtree;
        }
        else
        {
            comparisonCount++;
            //0 or 1 child
            Node* temp = t;
            if(t->leftChild != NULL)
                t = t->leftChild;
            else if(t->rightChild != NULL)
                t = t->rightChild;
            delete temp;
        }

        //update height
        t->height = max(getHeight(t->leftChild), getHeight(t->rightChild)) + 1;

        int balance = getBalance(t);

        if(balance > 1 && getBalance(t->leftChild) >= 0)
            return rotateWithRightChild(t);
        if(balance > 1 && getBalance(t->leftChild) < 0)
        {
            t->leftChild = rotateWithLeftChild(t->leftChild);
            return rotateWithRightChild(t);
        }
        if(balance < -1 && getBalance(t->rightChild) <= 0)
            return rotateWithLeftChild(t);
        if(balance < -1 && getBalance(t->rightChild) > 0)
        {
            t->rightChild = rotateWithRightChild(t->rightChild);
            return rotateWithLeftChild(t); 
        }

    }

    return t;
}
```

So I need the remove function to remove a specified node and rebalance the tree when necessary using the appropriate rotations. However, I keep getting a segmentation fault whenever I try to call the function in my main. Thanks.

Comment: _"I know the issue is with the rebalancing of the tree rather than the initial deletion of a node."_ Are these two aspects in different functions? If it's so easy for you to split the functionality like this in your head, it is very likely that the functionality should similarly be split in your code.

Comment: I have a theory as to what is wrong, but your code is too incomplete for me to test the theory. Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. First is the `removeMin` function and the `else if` part in `remove` function when the node to be deleted has two children.

Basic aim of the `removeMin` function should be to find the inorder successor of the node to be deleted which is `t` in your case. Consider the case when `t` has 2 children (both leaf nodes) then your `removeMin` function will set `t->leftChild` as `t->rightChild->rightChild` which is `NULL` which is wrong. Also the restructuring of the tree should be done inside `remove` hence `removeMin` becomes:

```
Node* AVL::removeMin(Node* node) // returns inorder successor of 't'
{
    if(node->left == NULL)
        return node;
    return removeMin(node->left);
}
```

Coming to `remove` function, we reset `t->key` with `minRightSubtree->key` and the node to be deleted now is `minRightSubtree`. But notice that the order of keys has changed in the chain from node `t` till node `minRightSubtree`. `t->key` is less than all the keys of nodes till before `minRightSubtree`. Hence you cannot just `delete minRightSubtree`, you have to call `remove` function on the node `minRightSubtree` which will take care of restructuring this chain. Also you can get a little help from the recursion stack to get the correct child for the current node `t` after deletion/rotation:

```
Node* AVL::remove(Node* &t, int num)
{
    if (t == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if (num > t->key)
        t->rightChild = remove(t->rightChild, num);
    else if (num < t->key)
        t->leftChild = remove(t->leftChild, num);
    else if (t->leftChild != NULL && t->rightChild != NULL)
    {
        //2 children
        Node* minRightSubtree = removeMin(t->rightChild);
        t->key = minRightSubtree->key;
        t->rightChild = remove(t->rightChild, minRightSubtree->key);
    }
    else
    {
        //0 or 1 child
        Node* temp = t;
        if (t->leftChild != NULL)
            t = t->leftChild;
        else if (t->rightChild != NULL)
            t = t->rightChild;

        if(temp == t)
            t = NULL;
        delete temp;
    }

    if (t == NULL)          // this case was added since there is a possibility of deleting 't'
        return NULL;

    //update height
    t->height = max(getHeight(t->leftChild), getHeight(t->rightChild)) + 1;

    int balance = getBalance(t);

    if (balance > 1 && getBalance(t->leftChild) >= 0)
        return rotateWithRightChild(t);
    if (balance > 1 && getBalance(t->leftChild) < 0)
    {
        t->leftChild = rotateWithLeftChild(t->leftChild);
        return rotateWithRightChild(t);
    }
    if (balance < -1 && getBalance(t->rightChild) <= 0)
        return rotateWithLeftChild(t);
    if (balance < -1 && getBalance(t->rightChild) > 0)
    {
        t->rightChild = rotateWithRightChild(t->rightChild);
        return rotateWithLeftChild(t);
    }
    return t;
}
```

I'm assuming your code for updating heights and balancing the rooted sub-tree is correct since I've forgotten about it's theory and will need to revise.

Comment: Ah yes I understand your adjustment for the removeMin function. Thank you. I also understand what you are saying about the minRightSubtree part. However, when I edited it to call remove again rather than just delete it, I get an error saying "error for object 0x7fc2a15000c0: pointer being freed was not allocated." I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Ah I see, in `else` part of `remove`, if `t` gets deleted (when `t` has 0 child), you have to set `t = NULL`. I added that into the code. Also note that I had not made changes only to the `else if` block prior to this edit. Hopefully this fixes the error.

Comment: Ah yes I think that's it! I got it all working now, I really appreciate your tips - your explanations were super helpful!